# Writing posts on my Facebook page without auth/js

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I'm working on a small Facebook application. I created the application with the developer app - then I created the Facebook Page. Now I want to post some status messages on the page AS the page. Not with my username or someone else. My problem is, I don't have rights to do that:

```
<?php
    require "_facebook/facebook.php";

    function getToken($appID, $appSecret)
    {
        return str_replace('access_token=', '', file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id='.$appID.'&client_secret='.$appSecret));
    }


    $pAppID     = 'XXXXX';
    $pAppSec    = 'XXXXX';
    $pSiteID    = 'XXXXX';


    $pToken = getToken($pAppID, $pAppSec);
    $pFacebook = new Facebook( array( 'appId'  => $pAppID, 'secret' => $pAppSec ));

    $args = array(
      'access_token'  => $pToken,
      'method'    => 'stream.publish',
      'message'       => "Test",
      'target_id'   => $pSiteID
    );
    $pRet = $pFacebook->api("/". $pSiteID ."/feed","post",$args);

    var_dump($pRet);
?>
```

Sadly, I just get an error as a response "**The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action**"

My problem is, I am not able to use JavaScript to authenticate, I don't want to connect with my real Facebook account also. Everything should be automatic. So help in any way would be great. I'm really stuck in here ..

Best regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post on a Facebook wall as Page, not as user](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5326537/post-on-a-facebook-wall-as-page-not-as-user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this question: (i had an earlier answer here which was incorrect):

[Posting to a Facebook Page as the Page (not a person)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6239482/posting-to-a-facebook-page-as-the-page-not-a-person)

The docs, if you want to implement this yourself are at
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#pagelogin

Follow the instructions there to log in as the page
and then use the access token you have for the Page to make posts on that Page's behalf.